# c++ list, push_back, & templates?

Tags: c++, templates, object, push-back

I am having a very difficult time using push_back on a template object. Can anyone explain why this works

```
    list<int> mylist;
    int myInt;
    mylist.push_back(myInt);
```

but this won't.

```
    list<KeyValuePair<T>> mylist;
    int myInt;
    mylist.push_back(myInt);
```

Comment: What do you expect the latter code to do?

Comment: KeyValurPair id a C# class, use std::pair<int, int>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A list is a list of some templated objects. You instantiate a list of int objects with:

```
list<int> mylist;
```

This list now 'knows' it will be managing int objects.

One of the list methods is push_back() wich adds objects of the templated object type to the end of the list.

You instantiate a list of KeyValuePair objects with:

```
list<KeyValuePair<T>> mylist;
```

This second list is for managing KeyValuePair objects

Now if you try to add int objects to a list of KeyValuePair objects, this will fail because this list is a list of KeyValuePair objects, not int objects.

Answer (score 0):

The second list is declared to store object of type `KeyValuePair<T>`. Thats why its not allowing your to push_back() of type int.